# js Date to Bson Timestamp

Tags: mongodb, bson

how to get Bson `Timestamp` from js `Date`?

```
const { Timestamp } = require('mongodb')


const jsDate = new Date("Tue, 27 Aug 2019 09:09:59 GMT")
const startAtOperationTime = ???      

const changeStream = db.watch({ startAtOperationTime })
```

mongo [db.watch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.watch/#db.watch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your usage:

```
const ordinal = 1
const seconds = parseInt( jsDate.getTime() / 1000 )
const startAtOperationTime = new Timestamp(ordinal, seconds)
```

[BSON Timestamp](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps) contains not only the seconds since the Unix epoch, but also the incrementing ordinal number of the operation (multiple operations occur in one second is common for the database). Just pass 1 if you don't care or don't know what `ordinal` is, it means starting with the first operation of one second.